# deploying UWP on windows 10 iot error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, registry, iot, raspberry-pi3

I created a simple application that run a webserver on raspberry pi 3 (background application (iot)); First time i deployed it correctly, then I modified code and from then, I cannot deploying anything (I see application in windows 10 iot as deployed, but it does not start); it give me an error as in image.

[image]

I ahve tried to create another solution, same result. I tried to create a node.js web server; same result. I don't know how solve this problem.

Comment: Can you show the error information in your question in English?

Comment: Solved! Thank you! It was sd card on raspberry; suddenly it stopped to work.